# Convergence in the Tychonoff topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

This is Example 10.2(b) (p.70) in Willard's *General Topology*:

> In the product space $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$, a sequence $f_n$
>   converges to $f$ iff $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ for each $x \in
>  \mathbb{R}$. This is clear once it is remembered that basic nhoods of
>   $f \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ have the form  $$U(f,F,\epsilon) = \{
>  g \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}: |g(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon \text{ for each
>  } x \in F \}$$
>
> for $F$ a **finite subset** of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon>0$.

Question: Why must $F$ be finite? Will the convergence still hold if $F$ is infinite?

Comment: Do you understand what the topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is in this example?

Comment: @ArthurFischer: Ah, now I understand why $F$ must be finite. It is because of the definition of tychonoff topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$, right?

Comment: @Idonknow: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

If $F$ is infinite then you obtain a stronger than pointvise convergence.